# Find the smallest number of vertices in a cubic graph with a bridge.

Tags: graph-theory

Find the smallest number of vertices in a cubic graph with a bridge.
I've found that the smallest number of vertices is 10 vertices, but now I need to prove that that actually is the smallest number and I'm not really sure how to go about the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Call your bridge $uv$, and consider the two component graphs of $G - uv$; call them $G_1$ which contains $u$ and $G_2$ which contains $v$. Suppose $|G_1| = 4$. Then $u$ has degree 2 in $G_1$ and the remaining vertices have degree 3. But no graph can have an odd number of vertices of odd degree. Therefore $|G_1| \ge 5$. This extends to $G_2$.